# mySQL SELECT IN from string

Tags: mysql

Here is my table X:

```
id      vals
---------------------
1       4|6|8|
```

Now table Y:

```
id      name
--------------------
1        a
4        b
6        c
8        d
```

Now I want the following:

```
select * from Y where id IN (replace(select vals from X where id = '1'),'|',',')
```

But this does not seem to work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead of just `IN`, normal `IN` keyword couldn't search between comma seperated values within one field.

For example

```
mysql> select FIND_IN_SET(4, replace('4|6|8|','|',','));

+-------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET(4, replace('4|6|8|','|',',')) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is definitely more concise than regexp; one of the reasons that I love SO is finding out about handy things like this I haven't seen before. :)

Comment: @Dav exactly my thoughts, +1 S.Mark for this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace gives you a string back - but it's a string value, not a string as in part of your query.

What you can do is instead of using `IN`, use a REGEXP to match within your original string, for example:

```
vals REGEXP '[[:<:]]4[[:>:]]'
```

would be true only if there is a "4" in the original string that isn't part of a larger number (thus if you have 3|44|100 it wouldn't match on "4" but would match on "44").

The `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are "left side of word" and "right side of word" respectively.

To generate that string, you can do something like...

```
CONCAT('[[:<:]]', CAST(id AS CHAR), '[[:>:]]')
```